# How do I query for values grouped by unique values in core data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

[image: Core Data Model]

Consider the above model with to-many relation.

Let's assume I am querying to get managed-objects where patient first or last name is "xyz" (there are multiple records of "xyz").

How to get a unique "xyz" as dictionary object and repeated "xyz" Managed-objets as objects in that dictionary.

So far I am able to get distinct values and also I am able to get array of managed objects where "xyz" is the predicate string.

But I am unable to think of a way to get array of dictionaries with its objects as managed-objects of duplicate values.

I want to have an array of dictionaries with unique value as dictionary name and objets in dictionary should be managed-objects/dictionaries.

Could somebody please help me with this. I will provide more explanation if any part is not understood.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#pragma mark - Search Patients By Patient Name

-(NSArray*)GetBillsForPatientwith:(NSString*)name{

NSMutableArray *AllBillsData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSArray *_strings = [self GetSplitStrings:name];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [CoreDataManager GetCoreDataManager].managedObjectContext;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:_Claims inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"patient_FirstName" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
NSMutableArray *subPredicates = [NSMutableArray array];


for (NSString *strings in _strings) {
    [subPredicates addObject:
     [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"patient_FirstName CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR patient_LastName contains[cd] %@",strings,strings]];
}
NSCompoundPredicate *predicate_ = [[NSCompoundPredicate alloc]initWithType:NSOrPredicateType subpredicates:subPredicates];
[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate_];
fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"patient_FirstName"],[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"patient_LastName"], nil];
//fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"patient_FirstName"],[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"patient_LastName"], nil];

NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
    // Handle the error.
}

for (NSDictionary *names in fetchedObjects) {
    // [AllBillsData addObject:names];
    [AllBillsData addObject:[self GetCorrespondingClaimsForNames:names]];
}
return AllBillsData;
}
//Entangled Method
-(NSArray*)GetCorrespondingClaimsForNames:(id)Names{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [CoreDataManager 
GetCoreDataManager].managedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:_Claims inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"patient_FirstName" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    NSMutableArray *subPredicates = [NSMutableArray array];
    [subPredicates addObject:
     [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"patient_FirstName ==[cd] %@ AND patient_LastName ==[cd] %@",[Names valueForKey:@"patient_FirstName"],[Names valueForKey:@"patient_LastName"]]];

    NSCompoundPredicate *predicate_ = [[NSCompoundPredicate alloc]initWithType:NSOrPredicateType subpredicates:subPredicates];
    [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate_];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }

    return fetchedObjects;

}
```